# Как решить проблему с комметариями js babel?

Tags: javascript

```
function() {
let a = 1;
}

// описание
function clone() {
let b = 1;
}
```

balel конвертирует вот так:

```
function main() {
  let a = 1;
} // описание


function clone() {
  let b = 1;
}
```

Причем не важно, gulp-babel или нет, даже онлайн конвертор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что не так?...

Comment: А зачем вам babel? Не конвертируйте сторонними приблудами ваш код и тогда он будет под вашим контролем.

Comment: Я слышал Без babel IE будет ругаться, или это в прошлом ?

Comment: Используйте многострочный комментарий для описания фукнции, однострочный для описания строки, babel посчитал что вы описываете строку

Comment: Про ругатся все зависит от версий и какие методы и как вы пишите код и делаете ли вы поддержку IE...

Comment: @Greg В 2021 об IE можно не переживать. Роль самого "не такого" браузера в современном мире выполняет Safari

Comment: @Darth Сафари это сплошной баг, тут согласен, у них и событие `DOMContentLoaded` срабатывает часто после window  `load` если страница закеширована, но у фаерфокса тоже бывает разные баги (особенности), встречал что обсервер в хроме и фаерфоксе по разному работают и срабатывают, но babel тут ничем не поможет)

Answer (score 2):

Как - очень просто: комментарии такого рода писать в общепринятой нотации [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/about-getting-started.html) :)

[image: Похоже что в REPL все ок]

---

А при локальном использовании Babel, стоит попробовать включить опцию [`retainLines`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#retainlines) (ну и другие опции в документации поискать... она для того и пишется, чтобы ее читали).
Кстати, рабочее использование данного транспайлера предполагает именно *локальную установку*: которую можно и настроить, и связать с остальными средствами разработки (REPL на сайте - годится для демонстрации, это **не** полноценный инструмент).

Comment: Если написать еще одну функцию, уже некорректно отображается

Comment: @НарбекАбдуллаев, в чем именно некорректность, какая версия babel используется, и что на твои замечания отвечают мейнтейнеры в https://github.com/babel/babel/issues ?

Comment: Там выше сделал скриншот,

Comment: @НарбекАбдуллаев, _"Там выше сделал скриншот"_ - раз для тебя скриншот отвечает на все уточняющие вопросы, то предлагаю тебе со скриншотом и беседовать))

Comment: Второе описание немного выше функций

Comment: Версия последняя